# Chatter mobile not showing publisher actions or mobile smart actions

Tags: mobile, chatter-mobile

Publisher actions documents  says these are avaliable in chatter mobile by adding mobile smart actions to gloabal layout.

I have added the mobile smart actions to global layout  but chatter mobile doesn't show the actions.  Am I missing any required configuration any work around for this ?